# Permutations List<List<Integer>>

Tags: java, permutation

I have a list with 42 entries. It looks like this:

```
[[2, 3, 8], [2, 3, 5, 8], [3, 5], ...]
```

I would like to generate all permutations from a tuple in the list.
It should begin with the first tuples. For example:

```
[[2, 3], [2, 3], [5,3]]
[[2, 8], [2, 3], [5,3]]
[[3, 8], [2, 3], [5,3]]
[[3, 2], [2, 3], [5,5]]
[[8, 3], [2, 3], [5,3]]
[[8, 2], [2, 3], [5,3]]
[[2, 3], [3, 2], [5,3]]
```

Then the tuples should be generated for the second entry in the list and so far.
At the end i would like to have a  List<List<List>> with all tuple combinations for the entries in the list.

This means first i have to generate all permutations from `[2, 3, 8]`. Than from `[2, 3, 5, 8]` and so far. This should be included in the final list.

I just started to fill the list for the example.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> possibleDrivers = new ArrayList<>();
        possibleDrivers.add(fill(new Integer[]{2, 3, 8}));
        possibleDrivers.add(fill(new Integer[]{2, 3, 5, 8}));
        possibleDrivers.add(fill(new Integer[]{3, 5}));

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(possibleDrivers.toArray()));
    }

    public static List<Integer> fill(Integer[] driver) {
        List<Integer> routeDay = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(routeDay, driver);

        return routeDay;
    }
}
```

How can I generate all pairs/permutations for this problem?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Is this a homework exercise? Because stackoverflow won't just give you the entire answer for a homework exercise, that would be unfair.

Comment: No. Its not a homework exercise. I try to solve an optimization task. I want to compare different algorithm (genetic algo, tabu search, etc.). But its hard to find the optimum. Bruteforce would be a suitable solution.

Comment: I believe for permutations that the only option is in fact brute-force

Comment: Yes. In the beginning i had a 2d array of a size of 924. So the number of permutations was 2^924. Its a litte bit to big to brutforce. So i tried to extract just the valid options to shorten it like in the list shown in the post. Maybe it works better. But i have no idea how to generate all permutations in this way.

Comment: Instead of `fill()`, why don't you use `List.of(2,3,5,8)` or if you're stuck with ancient Java versions use `Arrays.asList(2,3,5,8)`?

Answer (score 0):

The Number of Permutations is always n!. So you start with the first element of the first element and pair it with every element of the second element. Continue with the second from the first element and so on. But before saving them in the final list, check if they are already in there and depending on your requirements either save them as duplicate or throw the pair away.

Comment: it is n! not n^2

Comment: I think i didnt explained my problem so well. I have to generate all permutation from [2, 3, 8] ([2,3],[2,8][3,8],[3,2],[8,2],[8,3]), this should be connected to the second entry.